# Why does a Teams Tab based on a SharePoint Framework-WebPart open a Webbrowser?

Tags: spfx-webparts, microsoft-teams

A SharePoint Framework-WebPart, that is added to a Microsoft Teams-Team as a Tab, works fine for most users- but for a few users a Webbrowser opens when they try to open that Tab in their mobile Teams, trying to load the SharePoint Website that is linked to the Microsoft Teams-Team - but that Website does not open either.
The users that report the issue are using a current version of the Microsoft Teams-mobile app.
How can this issue be prevented?

Comment: If it is affecting only a small group of users, that usually points to a permissions issue...

Comment: Are their Teams apps updated? I believe this was only fully supported starting sometime in November 2019

Comment: their Teams apps have been installed in 2020